# Based on user id, determine if a user is an app user for your app (php, not fbml!)

Tags: php, facebook

I know of the FBML tag to see if ["is app user"](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/if-is-app-user/) for an id, but how can I determine that within PHP itself?

Comment: They also don't seem to include many examples for PHP...I had to spend an hour of googling simply figuring out how to get that friend list in the first place.

Comment: There is no way using the FB's API to know if a user installed/authorized your app. It's up to you to store that information when user authorizes it for the first time. By the way, Facebook doesn't send you a valid user session with an user id if the user did not authorized first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that i have misread the question. if you want to know if your user is an app user  or not you cannot use the graph api.

When a user comes to your application for the first time facebook sends you some data regarding that user. At that time you can decide what to do with that information. An easy way would be to use a database and store the id of that user so you can later use it when you want to check if other users have used your app or not.